# How to say "[someone] as [someone]" in movie credits?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, preposiciones

I'm doing a credits scene in a Spanish video, and I want to say "[someone] as [someone]."

For example,

> Harrison Ford **as** Han Solo

except in Spanish.

Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's:

**Harrison Ford** *como* **Han Solo**